# Error while uploading file through form in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to save a file and some other details in django using forms.
And I only want it to save a CharField and a FileField but not the country field.
For country field I want it to take its value through a post request. 
But the form isn't saving. The errors says "data didn't validate".
Also this method works fine if I don't use a FileField.

**models.py**

```
class Simple(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.FileField(upload_to='marksheet')
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

**forms.py**

```
class SimpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Simple
        fields = ['name','city']
```

**A snippet from upload.html**

```
<form action="upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label>Test input</label>
        <input type="text" name="country">
        {{form.name}}
        {{form.city}}
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**views.py**

```
def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        a = request.POST.get('country')
        form = SimpForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.country = a
            post.save()
            return HttpResponse('saved')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('ERROR SAVING')
    else:
        form = SimpForm()
        return render(request,'upload.html',{'form':form})
```

Comment: It'd be helpful if you can paste the full error stacktrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing [**`request.FILES`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.FILES) in your form. You should pass it like this:

```
form = SimpForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

More information on file uploads can be found [in documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/file-uploads/).

Comment: Thanks you so much for answering.